# Find the max and min combination of close points (sepearted by a particular distance

Tags: c

Suppose there are **n** points on a line. For each valid i, the position of the i-th point is Xi(integer and increasing).

A point is said to be **close** if the distance between it and adjacent is less than or equal to a specific distance ( our case 2 ).

Find the **best**(longest consecutive chain) and **worst**(shortest consecutive chain) possible cases of these **close** numbers.

**Input:**

```
5 // value of n 
1 2 5 6 7 // position of points
```

**Expected Output:**

```
2 //min
3 //max
```

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int T, N;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    while(T--)
    {    
        scanf("%d",&N);
        int *X;

        X = (int *)malloc((N)*sizeof(int));

        int k = 0 , j = 0, i, l;
        int max = 1, count1 = 1, count2 = 1;

        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&X[i]);
        }

        while(k<N)
        {
            for(i=k;i<N-1;i++)
            {
                if((X[i+1]-X[i])<=2)
                {
                    count1+=1;
                    if(count1>=max) max = count1;
                }

                else
                {                 
                    count1 = 1;
                    break;
                }                
            }
            if(i==N-1) break;
            else k++;
        }

        int min = N-max;

        while(j<N)
        {
            for(l=j;l<N-1;l++)
            {
                if((X[l+1]-X[l])>2)
                {
                    count2+=1;
                    if(count2<min) min = count2;
                }

                else
                {                 
                    count2 = 1;
                    break;
                }                
            }
            if(l==N-1) break;
            else j++;
        }

        if(max==N) 
        {   
            min=N;
            printf("%d %d\n",min,max);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("%d %d\n",min,max);
        }

        free(X);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Error:**
There are no errors when i am compiling it with the given test cases but the errors occur for case like `1 5 7 10` the output should be `1 2` but i am getting '2 2'

Comment: What do you mean by "*but the solution is not accepted by the website*" - Any error message? Maybe the website is faulty.

Comment: Why should min be N-max? And why should max be at least 1?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio the website is codechef which says it as a wrong answer

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio max should be at least = 1 since the point itself would be termed as a close point. Also by seeing the test cases, i  calculated min = N-max... if it is not then what it should be???

Comment: The description does not suggest that a point could be considered close to itself. And min = N-max in the example is a coincidence. For example, the sequence 1 2 3 would have both min and max as 3.

Comment: @GoodDeeds a point itself is considered a **close** point. I have edited the logic please have a look

Comment: But if a point is considered close to itself, then min should always be 1, which is not the case in the example output you have given.

Comment: Your algorithm is simply wrong. First, the points are given in increasing order, so there is no need to go hunting for close points with a loop. If a point has a close neighbor, they are next to each other in the input. So you do not even need to store the input in an array. Initialize `max` to 0 and `min` to `N`. To start examining the points, remember the first point, remember that there is only one point in the current sequence. The look at each following point. If it is close to the preceding point, add one to the number of points in the current sequence…

Comment: … If it is not close to the preceding point, then the previous sequence has ended. Compare its length to `min` and `max` and update those accordingly. Then reset the length of the current sequence to one and go on. After you have looked at the last point, the final sequence ended, so again compare its length to `min` and `max` and update those accordingly. Then you are done.

Comment: Example for 1 5 7 10: Remember 1. Look at 5. It is not close to 1, so the sequence ended. It had length 1, so update `min` to 1 and `max` to 1. The new sequence, containing just 5 so far, has length 1. Look at 7. It is close to 5, so the sequence now has length 2. Look at 10. It is not close to 7, so the sequence ended. It has length 2, so update `max` to 2. The new sequence, containing just 10 so far, has length 1. There are no new numbers, so that was the last sequence. Its length, 1, does not cause any change to `min` or `max`. So we are done, `min` is 1, and `max` is 2.

Comment: @GoodDeeds: “Close” is a relation between two points. A sequence of close points may be defined as a sequence x_0, x_1, x_2,… x_n such that, for any j, x_j is close to x_j+1. With this definition, a sequence containing a single point is a sequence of close points even though “close” is not defined so that a point is close to itself.